# How do you explicitly throw an error?

Tags: vimscript

There are several wordings for this depending on what programming languages you are used to, but none of them turned up results for me. Also, neither `help abort()` nor `help raise()` nor `help throw()` gave me anything.

How would you explicitly throw an error?
How would you explicitly raise an error?
How would you explicitly abort?

I have in the past just written my errormessage directly, which is of course invalid code and raises an error, but I'd prefer to be clear about what I'm doing here.

```
function may_fail() abort
  let l:message = system('something')
  if v:shell_error
    there was a problem with something <- can I use an actual abort() or something here?
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: [`:h throw-catch`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#throw-catch)?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks! I see now that `:h throw` was what I needed, but normally for vimscript questions I'm supposed to add () to find functions.

Comment: `throw` is an Ex command not a function. :) The magic string for those is the `:` prefix rather than the `()` suffix: `:h :throw`.

Comment: If you're not sure which one it is two options are 1) do a general search with `:helpgrep` or 2) look for it in both `:h function-list` and `:h ex-cmd-index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found [the answer a little later on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312813/vim-showing-an-error-message-from-a-vim-script). It's not clear to me whether these vimscript questions should be on vi.stackexchange or on SO.

Use echoerr to output an error and continue, and throw to abort / raise an error:

```
echoerr 'some command failed with: '
throw l:output
```

Comment: Vimscript is absolutely on-topic here. _Anything_ related to official VIm and NeoVim is.

Comment: Technically, anything vi-like enough :)

Comment: Well, my answer wasn't intended to be comprehensive but, yes. :)